# Progress Bar on Promise.all array of $.ajax() calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, progress-bar

**FINAL UPDATE 25/06/20**: Okay, so there were multiple reasons this was not working.

1. $.ajax() is a pain to work with as it doesn't really return proper promises. So any implementations relying on that didn't work. Solution to this part was to change over to using AXIOS for the calls.
2. I'm actually making a lot of calls during this process. I initially thought that the first set of calls I was making was small, and didn't cause a lot of the loading time before the bar fills up. I was expecting the second set of calls to take a long time, and thus only coded the progress bar to take that into consideration. After analysing the network traffic, it turns out it was the complete reverse. So my solution was to actually have the progress bar fill up twice: once for the "preparation call" (which actually take the longest), and then fills up again on response of the actual request calls.

Thanks to all that gave their advice, it helped once I figured out where I was going wrong!

---

**UPDATE 25/06/20**: Here is a link to the Gist with the entire function as it is too big to post here: [Function in Gist](https://gist.github.com/cglatot/20906fe896afa46bd9452a07e7f99bb3). Line 215 is where I add the $.ajax() calls to matchPromises. Line 274 is where I call Promise.allSettled(matchPromises)

---

I am having a lot of issues trying to get a working progress bar for this. I'm not going to post my actual code as it's way too long, but I'll post the gist of it.

The ajax calls are something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    "url": myUrl,
    "method": "POST",
    "success": (data) => {
        doStuff
        // POINT A
     },
     "error": (data) => {
         doStuff
     }
})
```

I push them into an array called `matchPromises` and then I call `Promise.allSettled(matchPromises)` on that. This all works fine.

The problem I'm having is trying to update a progress bar to indicate how many promises are done. I have the following at the top of the function where I am doing everything else:

```
let currentProgress = 0;
let maxProgress = 0;

function displayProgress() {
    currentProgress++;
    let calculatedWidth = (currentProgress / maxProgress) * 100;
    $('#progressBar').width(`${calculatedWidth}%`);
    $('#progressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', currentProgress);
}
```

I update the maxProgress right before I call `Promise.allSettled(matchPromises)` by using `matchPromises.length`.

I have tried placing `displayProgress()` in the `success` part of the $.ajax calls - but the issue with that is that maxProgress will always stay at 0 every time it's called.

I've tried a ton of various methods of promisifying the `$.ajax` by wrapping it in a `new Promise` and adding `.then()` - and this correctly reads `maxProgress` - BUT no matter which method I've tried, it only calls this in a huge block AFTER the `Promise.allSettled` has finished.

I've been at this for hours and have tried so many different methods. Really hope someone out there can help me with this because I'm at the end of my tether.

Comment: "maxProgress will always stay at 0 every time it's called" Every time what is called? That is key. Need to see that code please.

Comment: Every time that displayProgress() is called. I updated the original post with a link to a Gist containing the entire function so you can see.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is some code lacking to apply that to your situation, I tried to sketch a helpful solution anyway.

I hope this solves your issue or at least gives you some inspiration.

```js
const getLongRunningPromise = (milliseconds, value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(value), milliseconds)
    });
};

const promises = [getLongRunningPromise(5000, 'a'), getLongRunningPromise(1000, 'b')];

let doneCount = 0;
const overallCount = promises.length;

const handleProgress = (result) => {
    doneCount++;
    const percentageDone = doneCount/overallCount*100;
    console.log(`${percentageDone}% Done`);
    return result;
};

Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.then(handleProgress))).then((results) => console.log('results', results));
```

Comment: This is a method I've tried, and it doesn't work. The promises all get handled first, and once ALL of them have completed, it then logs the percentageDone.

Comment: That is not true. I adopted my example to show that. It shows now that there is a difference of 4 seconds in the timestamp of the log entries. So after one second it logs `50% Done` and after additional 4 seconds it logs `100% Done` and logs the results.

Comment: I tried this again, and for whatever reason it just will not work with my code. I think it might have something to do with the fact that I'm using $.ajax() calls. I've updated my OP with a link to a gist for the original function.

Comment: Okay, I got to the bottom of this and updated the OP with reasons / results. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What a cool idea!  Hadn't seen this before but it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function `foo()`, you can write something like this:

```
function foo() {
    let currentProgress = 0;
    let someArray = .......;
    let matchPromises = someArray.map(function(myUrl) {
        return $.ajax({
            'url': myUrl,
            'method': 'POST',
            'success': (data) => {
                // doStuff
             },
             'error': (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                // doStuff
             }
        })
        .always(function() {
            displayProgress(++currentProgress, matchPromises.length);
        });
    });
    Promise.allSettled(matchPromises).then(...); // what happens here has nothing to do with displaying progress.
}

function displayProgress(current, max) {
    let calculatedWidth = (current / max) * 100;
    $('#progressBar').width(`${calculatedWidth}%`).attr('aria-valuenow', current);
}
```

Thus, `currentProgress` is an inner member of `foo()` and `maxProgress` never needs to be assigned - it's just `matchPromises.length`.

If it's not called elsewhere, `displayProgress()` could also be an inner member of `foo()`, or just move the two lines of code inside the `.always()` callback (and adapt accordingly).

Comment: The problem with this method is that I am dynamically creating the array, so assigning matchPromises.length at the point of adding the ajax to the array would give an increasing number as the array grows, and not the actual maximum

Comment: Yes, agreed, having looked at the Gist code, I now understand that `matchPromises` is created not just *dynamically* but also *asynchronously*.